# How to register Firebird data provider for Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, firebird, provider

How do I register a Firebird data provider to use it with Entity Framework?
What should I do to make it appear in the `Entity Data Model Wizard/Choose Data Source` window?
[image]
<sub>(source: [rafaelromao at sites.google.com](https://sites.google.com/site/rafaelromao/ChooseDataSource.png))</sub>

I expect it to appear in the `Data sources:` or `Data provider:` lists.
Is it possible? Or I need to configure this connection another way?

PS: The provider I'm trying to use is the FirebirdClient 2.5

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to install DDEX Provider for Visual Studio

http://www.firebirdsql.org/index.php?op=files&id=netprovider

http://web.firebirdsql.org/firebirdtutorial/firebird-data-access-designer-ddex-installation.html

Comment: Thank you for this useful answer. I'd like to point out that although the DDEX provider doesn't work under Visual Studio Express, it works under the free Visual Studio shell. One can create the model under the shell, then get back to the Express edition to modify and use it.

Comment: Updated link to Firebird Provider Tools downloads (for them who search this answer in 2016+): http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/additional-downloads/

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the Firebird .net Provider 3.0 and the DDEX Provider 3.0 there is an installer, where you can select for which VS versions you want the provider to be installed.

[image: DDEX Provider with selection of VS version]

http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/